# Java EE - How webserver handles long running http request

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, httprequest

I am currently working in a web application that will trigger a long running database procedure once the controller received the request (request is currently an AJAX request).

My controller looks something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/startProcedureCall.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
protected void startProcedureCall(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //do some stuff
    //...
    //...
    myService.callProcedure(); //<- this procedure may run upto an hour
    //... do some stuff
    //...
}
```

The request will stay in the controller until the `myService.callProcedure()` finishes its execution, which as what was stated in the code comment, may run upto an hour.

My concern is that, will the web server permit a request to be trapped in a controller for such a long time? Will this not result to a some kind of a timeout error?

I am currently using websphere as web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your web server is configured. Resources like [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/sr/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sr.doc/cwsr_planning_install16_soap.html) one will show you how to configure timeout settings for your version of WebSphere.

Keep in mind though that you might want to consider a different architecture like asynchronous batch jobs (for example with [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/)) and caching. Just a thought though.